# Geometrically symmetric operations

Tags: python, math, inverse

This might seem a little strange, but I'm trying to extend a number of arithmetic concepts to a geometric space and I'm having no shortage of stopping blocks. The specific issue this time is coming up with an equivalent of a least-square metric for the geometric space.

For instance squaring has this feature arithmetically since the arithmetic inverse is just negation. In code:

```
def arithmetically_symmetric(a):
    return a**2

arithmetically_symmetric(a) == arithmetically_symmetric(-a)
>>> True
arithmetically_symmetric(a) == arithmetically_symmetric(b)
>>> False
```

In a geometric space however, the inverse is inversion, and for the life of me I can't figure out a way to do this without just having some kind of case statement. Basically I'm looking for a function that working like this:

```
geometrically_symmetric(a) == geometrically_symmetric(1/a)
>>> True
geometrically_symmetric(a) == geometrically_symmetric(b)
>>> False
```

The last condition is added so that the trivial solution of:

```
def geometrically_symmetric(a):
    return a * 1/a
```

Isn't an option.

Specifically I'm looking for a solutions that's NOT:

```
def geometrically_symmetric(a):
    if a < 1:
        return 1/a
    return a
```

Because my primary complaint here is theoretical rather than practical.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the primary problem is mathematical; if you knew the answer, implementing it in Python would be trivial. So it probably belongs elsewhere, like [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Have you considered getting a book on geometry or topology? This sounds like something that has probably been reasonably well studied.

Comment: @abarnert I tried that, but they thought it was too much like programming so I moved it over here...

Comment: Meanwhile, does the answer have to be within the same range as the domain (float or rational or whatever you're using), or can it be a 2D number (complex, dual, or hyperbolic)?

Comment: @abarnert I would be totally happy if the answer were 2D

Comment: @Marcin I've read a couple, and this really doesn't seem to be something that's really covered. It seems related to the general study of hyper-operators, but they aren't really heavily studied.

Comment: Come to think of it… this would probably be cheating mathematically, but maybe not programmatically… you don't even need a 2x2 matrix, just a 2-vector, which you can represent in Python as a tuple: `return max(a, 1/a), min(a, 1/a)`.

Comment: @abarnert That's equivalent to the last code sample, no?

Comment: @SlaterTyranus: Equivalent in that it's correct in the exact same cases, but that's kind of implied by the question. It's certainly not returning the same thing. If you don't like the use of `max`, you could avoid it by operating on a pair of dual numbers instead (I'd have to think through the details) so there's nothing but "elementary" math.

Comment: Since `log()` maps `1/x` to `-y`, any symmetric function of `log(x)` should let you do what you want.  As @tom10 mentions, `log(x)**2` works fine, but a more natural function might be `exp(log(x)**2) == x**log(x)`, or perhaps `exp(-log(x)**2) == x**(-log(x))`

Comment: Note that the above mentioned `max(a,1/a)` can be expressed as a symmetric function of `log(a)`:   `max(a,1/a) == exp(abs(log(a)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need it to work on positive numbers, this is easy:

```
def gs(a):
    return a**2 + (1/a**2)
```

That result is shared by any positive number with its own multiplicative inverse, and with no other positive number. For example, `gs(2) == gs(0.5) == 4.25`.

---

Unfortunately, it's also shared with its arithmetic inverse: `gs(2) == gs(0.5) == gs(-2) == gs(-0.5) == 4.25`.

But we can fix that just by copying the sign:

```
def gs(a):
    return (a**2 + (1/a**2)) * abs(a)/a
```

Now, `gs(2) == gs(0.5) == 4.25 != gs(-2) == gs(0.5) == -4.25`.

If you don't like the `abs` because there's a hidden `if` in there… well, there isn't. Sticking with floats, you can obviously do `a**2**.5`.

---

So that gets us all non-zero floats. And zero is obviously outside the domain, because `gs(0)` should be equal to `gs(1/0)`, which is not a number.

It still doesn't work for complex numbers, however—`gs(i) == 2i == gs(-1/i)`, but `gs(1/i) == -2i == gs(-i)`. For that, you just need multiply by the conjugate instead of squaring.

Answer (score 1):

How about the square of the logarithm?  Something like

```
import math

def geometrically_symmetric(a):
    x = math.log(a)
    return x*x

geometrically_symmetric(2.) == geometrically_symmetric(.5)   # True

geometrically_symmetric(2.) == geometrically_symmetric(.6)   # False
```

Comment: But that only works on positive numbers, and positive numbers are easy—you can just do `a**2 + (1/a**2)`.

Comment: @abarnert: OP doesn't really define what he wants to happen in this case, so I'm not going out of my way to address it.  There are multiple solutions that are "geometrically symmetric", and I just introduced this to remind the OP that log converts multiplication to addition, which is useful to think about in this type of problem.

Comment: Yeah it's definitely helpful to understanding the problem. But I think it's pretty obvious what he wants to happen in this case: `gs(-2) == gs(-.5)`. What else could he mean?

Comment: Really, I'm just not going to waste my time guessing at what he means.  If you feel you know, then more power to you.

Comment: You think `geometrically_symmetric(a) == geometrically_symmetric(1/a)` is not clear enough? It seems pretty obvious to me what that means for `a==-2`.

Comment: It just depends on the case, and I really have no idea what he wants.  It's really great if you do, I'm really, really impressed, but what do you want from me?  I assume he's doing this to solve a real problem, and in a real situation, one or the other approach might be preferred.  For example, your solution could be difficult to work with analytically (and the OP explicitly said he didn't want a conditional, and all you did was introduce this with an `abs` which is still difficult analytically).

Comment: I don't know why you're getting so defensive about this. If you don't want anyone commenting on your answers, maybe you shouldn't post answers on a site with comments-on-answers sections.

Comment: You said the same things three times. I told you I disagree, and that the OP doesn't specify.  Suggesting I get off this site is also ridiculous.  I really don't know what you want, and why you keep posting this same opinion over again.